# PHP Codeception instantiating Tester Class

Tags: php, codeception

I am new to PHP, so please forgive me. I did not write the whole code for brevity.

I want to to use JSWaiter function to be called before every step.

```
<?php
class Tester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    public function JSWaiter() {
        $this->waitForJS("return document.readyState == 'complete'", 20);
    }
}
```

So I tried to call instance of `Tester`, the error says "required parameter $scenario missing"

```
<?php
namespace Helper;
use Tester;

class EventListener extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function _beforeStep(\Codeception\Step $step) {
        $this->tester = new Tester();
    }
}
```

What exactly is the `$scenario` that I have to pass in?

Or how do I call Webdriver methods inside a class that extends `\Codeception\Module`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getModule method to get instance of WebDriver module.

```
$webdriver = $this->getModule('WebDriver');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped